# python how to convert str "09FEB2017" to date type

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have an str variable named day and I want to convert it to date

```
day = "09FEB2017"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the appropriates [`format codes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

```
day = "09FEB2017"
d = datetime.strptime(day, "%d%b%Y")
print(d)         # 2017-02-09 00:00:00
print(d.date())  # 2017-02-09
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

day = "09FEB2017"
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(day, '%d%b%Y')
```

does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/7539615

`datetime.strptime` will come in handy

Comment: It looks like this answer points out that a different Q&A already solves this question. If this is the case, please flag or vote this question as a *duplicate* of the other Q&A.

Comment: I tried to mark this as duplicate but was unable to do so. I pasted the link here which clearly explains how strings of different types can be converted to date, but somehow feels that it offended someone. Anyways, maybe half info is better than complete knowledge.